# Oracle database Connection request timed out

Tags: web8.5, oracle

We are using SDL Web 8.5 with Oracle database. most of the time we are facing "Connection request timed out" and it requires restart of all services. below is error with stack trace

```
Connection request timed out


Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.GetConnection()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation, FieldDictionary& dataFields)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.Execute(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Queuing.QueueConsumerDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.Queuing.IQueueConsumerDataMapper.FetchMessage(Int32 queueConsumerId)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Queuing.QueueConsumer.FetchMessage()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Queuing.QueueConsumer.RetrieveMessage(Int32 timeout)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchIndexer.QueueConsumerHandler.GetQueueMessage()
```

Comment: If not done already, running Oracle maintenance may help - https://docs.rws.com/792152/103638/sdl-web-8-5--retired-/maintaining-an-oracle-database

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace, it seems like you are trying to retrieve queue message or queue messages. If there are millions of messages, you will probably get timeout for it.

My point here is, that maybe your DB is ok, but it just can't handle the number of messages. What I would suggest to you is just try to remove old queue messages.

https://docs.rws.com/792152/105947/sdl-web-8-5--retired-/purging-queues

You can see the link above to purge search queue messages and then check again if you still have db issues.

Comment: Actually, the timeout happens when trying to establish the connection with Oracle.  So, *before* any queries are executed.  Seems to be an infrastructure issue.